# How to append values to generator while using bigrams in conditionalFreqDist method in python?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, probability

**Context:**
I'm using NLTK to generate bigram probabilities. I have a corpus from which I have generated bigrams.
-> 'wordPairsBigram' refers to the bigram from the corpus.
I have a sentence "The company chairman said he will increase the profit next year".
-> 'wordPairSentence' refers to the bigrams in the above sentence.

**The Problem:** I need to generate bigram probabilities. For that I need to find conditional Frequency Distribution of the sample sentence which I will pass onto the ConditionalProbDist function. I have the following code which calculates the conditional Frequency of the bigrams of the sentence that are available in the corpus.

```
fdListSentence1 = ConditionalFreqDist(wordBigram for wordBigram in wordPairsBigram if wordBigram in wordPairSentence1 )
print fdListSentence1.tabulate()

output:
        company   he said will year
     The    8    0    0    0    0
chairman    0    0    7    0    0
      he    0    0    0    2    0
    next    0    0    0    0    5
    said    0   21    0    0    0
```

**The issue** The code works fine for all the bigrams that are available in the corpus and the sample sentence. There are a few bigrams that are there in Sample sentence but not there in the corpus. They dont get included while calculating the frequency distribution.

**What I want?** I want the frequency distribution for the bigrams in the sentence. If the bigram in the sentence is not there in corpus bigram, I want a value 0 while tabulating.

Any help is appreciated. I dont know how to include what I want in the code.

Comment: is it possible for you to post the working code. Now with all the namespaces you are using and the camelcases, it's hard to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: in the code you are showing Bigram but when you output the table it's giving confusion matrix of single words.

Comment: Hi @alvas, my problem here is not smoothing. Its with respect to the generator. The corpus contains some bigrams. The sample sentence has bigrams. A few bigrams in sample sentence are not there in the corpus bigram. 
The code "wordBigram for wordBigram in wordPairsBigram if wordBigram in wordPairSentence1 " takes an intersection of bigram words in corpus and sample sentence.
Eg - A = Sample sentence bigrams, B = Corpus bigrams.
What's happening here is, A (intersection) B
What I want is, (A-B) U (A intersection B). Does it make sense ? or should I explain more ?

Comment: yes, please explain more in the post and i'll try my best to diagnose what is wrong =)

Comment: Okay. Lets say, my sentenceBigram = (A,B,C,K,L,P) {all these alphabets represent bigrams}. Corpus bigram has (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,A,B,C,D,G,G,B,C,A). I would like to have the frequency distribution of 'sentenceBigrams'. The code, 'wordBigram for wordBigram in corpusBigram if wordBigram in sentenceBigram', gives me only (A,B,C) and the freq distribution of A,B,C. I want A,B,C freq counts and also K,L,P freq count (these constitute sentenceBigram which don't occur in the corpus ) as 0. Does that help ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to smoothen the distribution. There are various ways of smoothing, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing.

Here's how one way of additive smoothing:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.util import bigrams
from nltk.probability import ConditionalFreqDist
from itertools import chain

train = brown.sents()[:100]
test = brown.sents()[101:110]

cfd = ConditionalFreqDist()
train_bigrams = list(chain(*[bigrams(i) for i in train]))
for bg in train_bigrams:
    cfd[bg[0]].inc(bg[1])

# Or if you prefer a one-liner. 
cfd = ConditionalFreqDist((bg[0],bg[1]) for bg in list(chain(*[bigrams(i) for i in train])))


for bg in list(chain(*[bigrams(i) for i in test])):
    prob = cfd[bg[0]].freq(bg[1])
    prob = 0.0001 if not prob else prob
    print bg, prob
```

**[out]:**

```
('said', 'it') 0.125
('it', 'would') 0.0001
('would', 'force') 0.111111111111
('force', 'banks') 0.0001
('banks', 'to') 0.0001
('to', 'violate') 0.0001
('violate', 'their') 0.0001
('their', 'contractual') 0.0001
('contractual', 'obligations') 0.0001
('obligations', 'with') 0.0001
('with', 'depositors') 0.0001
('depositors', 'and') 0.0001
('and', 'undermine') 0.0001
('undermine', 'the') 0.0001
('the', 'confidence') 0.0001
('confidence', 'of') 0.0001
('of', 'bank') 0.0001
('bank', 'customers') 0.0001
('customers', '.') 0.0001
('``', 'If') 0.0001
('If', 'you') 0.0001
('you', 'destroy') 0.0001
('destroy', 'confidence') 0.0001
('confidence', 'in') 0.0001
('in', 'banks') 0.0001
('banks', ',') 0.0001
(',', 'you') 0.0001
('you', 'do') 0.0001
('do', 'something') 0.0001
('something', 'to') 0.0001
('to', 'the') 0.0727272727273
('the', 'economy') 0.0001
('economy', "''") 0.0001
("''", ',') 0.205882352941
(',', 'he') 0.0001
('he', 'said') 0.0001
('said', '.') 0.166666666667
```